# jquery code flow

Tags: javascript, jquery

please I need some help with the flow of my jquery code. I have gotten the slideshow to work and decided to go a step further and add nav buttons/images.

in the code below, I am testing it out with one div first, the div will later become a picture or a button. anyways i have it so that when i click the div, the slideshow goes to the first image in the slide show.

Now the KEY ISSUE I am having is that with the code below it works but it takes 5 seconds after the click to show the first image, i'm guessing because of the timeout function.

Please note the this is just a snippet of the code contained in the function slideShow.

```
$("#slidecontrol2").click(function(){
    next.removeClass('is-showing');
    $('#container').children(':first').children(':first').addClass('is-showing');


  });

  setTimeout(slideShow, 5000);
```

I tried calling the function again after the click() function and before the timeout function.

```
 $("#slidecontrol2").click(function(){
        next.removeClass('is-showing');
        $('#container').children(':first').children(':first').addClass('is-showing');
        **slideShow ();**

      });

      setTimeout(slideShow, 5000);
```

it works but now my images are going crazy fast, and dare i click again, it speeds up and gets crazier.

Please help
ANYONE!!

Comment: Please add the code in question. This is hard to understand without seeing code.

Comment: do i just repost the question?

Comment: You shouldn't have to! Just edit your existing question.

Comment: Please, anyone out there to even point me in the right direction.

Comment: What does slideShow do?  Does it start the slideshow, or progress one slide ahead? Does it duplicate any of the functionality you have in the click handler?

Comment: slideShow just fades out the current image and fades in the next image with classes "is-showing", so I guess you can say it progresses, because as soon as I load my page the slideshow starts. As far as duplicating, not really, I am using the next variable to keep track of the next image ordinarily within the slideShow function.

Comment: and the code above including the timeout is in the slideShow function

Comment: Don't make `slideShow` recursive.  It shouldn't call itself unless you want the slides to automatically advance.  Also, you shouldn't have the click handler inside a recursively called function. Employ a separation of concerns: don't have the click handler inside `slideShow`.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that `slideShow` takes no parameters, so it must handle finding the "visible" slide and the next slide on its own.  It also seems to me that you would like the slideshow to happen automatically (which I gathered from you `setTimeout(slideShow, 5000);` line) AND you would like to progress to the next slide on click of the `slidecontrol2` element.  Since `slideShow` takes care of this progressive action, here's what your code should look like (pseudo-code below):

```
var slideShow = function(){
    //Fades out current image, 
    //finds next image with class "is-showing" and fades it in
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //Adds click handler to advance slideshow on click of button
    $("#slidecontrol2").click(function(){
        slideShow();
    });

    //Begins slideshow on load of page
    setTimeout(slideShow, 5000);
});
```